# Prove that the area of $\triangle DEF$ is twice the area of $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Let $\triangle ABC$  be an equilateral triangle and let $P$ be a point on its circumcircle. Let lines $PA$ and $BC$ intersect at $D$ , let lines $PB$ and $CA$ intersect at $E$, and let lines $PC$ and $AB$ intersect at $F$. Prove that the area of $\triangle DEF $ is twice the area of $\triangle ABC$.

---

I had used my method and it required that $\triangle DEF $ have to be isosceles triangle which means $ P $ should be the mid point of $\widehat {BC}$ or $\widehat{AC}$ or $\widehat {BC}$. But the problem does not said so. So, how to solve it correctly?

Comment: Maybe you can use induction? After proving that the isosceles $\triangle DEF$ has twice the area?

Comment: @JohnGlenn can I really use it .? There’s no other method? Is it available to use in high school problem ? Specially in geometry.

Comment: @John how can we use induction here? Thanks

Comment: @KingTut I guess we lay down a general form for all points, write lines as matrices, then solve the area using determinants. Is it possible though?

Comment: @John oops didnt notice your answer, will try to understand it

Comment: @KingTut the proof for the base case is not general though, it's very specific for $P(\frac12)$

Comment: There is actually no need to use a proof by induction!

Comment: very very interesting problem! I had much fun solving it with no trigonometry or even circumference equation. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: Can I ask you where this problem comes from? Was it taken from a book? Do you know which one?

Comment: @Matteo I am not so sure , my teacher asked me to do , but I believe it was a French Olympiad exercise!

Comment: Ok then I assume nobody will mind about my posting it in my blog... https://www.dfnu.xyz/index.php/2019/03/06/the-revenge-of-menelaus
thanks again!

Comment: @Matteo sure !! You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof (for the case when $P$ lies on arc $BC$):

Let $AB=BC=CA=1$ and $\angle PAC=\theta$.

$$\frac{PD}{\sin\angle PBD}=\frac{PB}{\sin \angle PDB} \implies \frac{PD}{\sin\theta}=\frac{PB}{\sin (120^\circ-\theta)} $$

$$\frac{PB}{\sin\angle PAB}=\frac{AB}{\sin \angle APB}\implies \frac{PB}{\sin(60^\circ-\theta)}=\frac{AB}{\sin 60^\circ}$$

So, $\displaystyle PD=\frac{\sin\theta\sin(60^\circ-\theta)}{\sin60^\circ\sin(120^\circ-\theta)}=\frac{\sin\theta\sin(60^\circ-\theta)}{\sin60^\circ\sin(60^\circ+\theta)}$.

$$\frac{PE}{\sin\angle PAC}=\frac{AE}{\sin \angle APE} \implies \frac{PE}{\sin\theta}=\frac{AE}{\sin 120^\circ} $$

$$ \frac{AE}{\sin\angle ABE}=\frac{AB}{\sin\angle AEB} \implies  \frac{AE}{\sin (60^\circ+\theta)}=\frac{AB}{\sin(60^\circ-\theta)}$$

So, $\displaystyle PE=\frac{\sin\theta\sin(60^\circ+\theta)}{\sin120^\circ\sin(60^\circ-\theta)}=\frac{\sin\theta\sin(60^\circ+\theta)}{\sin60^\circ\sin(60^\circ-\theta)}$.

$$\frac{PF}{\sin\angle PBF}=\frac{PB}{\sin \angle PFB} \implies \frac{PF}{\sin(120^\circ-\theta)}=\frac{PB}{\sin \theta}$$

So, $\displaystyle PF=\frac{\sin(120^\circ-\theta)\sin(60^\circ-\theta)}{\sin60^\circ\sin\theta}=\frac{\sin(60^\circ+\theta)\sin(60^\circ-\theta)}{\sin60^\circ\sin\theta}$.

The area of $\triangle DEF$ is

\begin{align*}
&\;\frac{1}{2}(PD\cdot PE+ PE\cdot PF+PF\cdot PD)\sin 120^\circ\\
=&\;\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left[\frac{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2(60^\circ+\theta)++\sin^2(60^\circ-\theta)}{\sin^260^\circ}\right]\\
=&\;\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\sin^2\theta+(\sin60^\circ\cos\theta+\cos60^\circ\sin\theta)^2+(\sin60^\circ\cos\theta-\cos60^\circ\sin\theta)^2\right]\\
=&\;\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\sin^2\theta+2\sin^260^\circ\cos^2\theta+\cos^260^\circ\sin^2\theta\right]\\
=&\;\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\frac{3}{2}\sin^2\theta+\frac{3}{2}\cos^2\theta\right]\\
=&\;\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align*}

The area of triangle $\triangle ABC$ is

$$\frac{1}{2}(1)^2\sin60^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

Answer (score 3):

It is very interesting to solve this problem by only using our greek friends Pythagoras and Menelaus, together with some simple algebra.

[image]

### Initial Observations

Without loss of generality assume that $P$ lies on the half-plane determined by $BC$ and not containing $A$. Note that there is no need to use the circle, once we fix $\angle BPC = 120°$. In the figure above I added point $G$ given by the intersection of line $FD$ with $AC$. Suppose also $\overline{AB}=1$.

Once $\overline{BF} = x$ is chosen, the entire Figure is defined. We aim therefore at showing that, independently of $x$,
$$[DEF] = 2[ABC].$$

### Characterization of $\triangle BFC$

Below the triangle in question has been isolated, to better help you in the demontrations.

[image]

Recall that $\overline{BC} = 1$ and $\overline{BF} = x$. 
Use Pythagorean Theorem on $\triangle CKF$ in oder to determine
$$\overline{CF} = \sqrt{x^2+x+1}.$$
From the similarity 
$$\triangle BPC \sim \triangle BCF,$$ 
show that
$$\overline{CF}\cdot\overline{CP} = 1,$$
so that, in the end, you have
$$
\begin{cases}
\overline{CF} = \sqrt{x^2+x+1},\\
\overline{CP} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}},\\
\overline{FP} = \frac{x(x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}.
\end{cases}
$$

### Four Applications of Menelaus's Theorem (MT)

MT on $\triangle ACF$ with the line $BE$, gives
$$\frac{\overline{CE}}{\overline{AE}} = \frac{1}{x+1}.$$
Together with $\overline{AE}-\overline{CE} = 1$ this leads to
$$\overline{CE} = \frac{1}{x}$$
and
$$\overline{AE} = \frac{x+1}{x}.$$

Similarly, MT on $\triangle BFC$ and line $AP$, with the known fact that $\overline{BD} + \overline{CD} = 1$ yields
$$\overline{CD} = \frac{1}{x+1}$$
and
$$\overline{DB} = \frac{x}{x+1}.$$
MT on $\triangle ABC$ and line $FG$, with $\overline{AG} + \overline{CG} = 1$, gives you
$$ \overline{AG} = \frac{x+1}{x+2}$$
and
$$ \overline{CG} = \frac{1}{x+2}.$$
Finally, MT on $\triangle CGF$ with line $AP$ yields
$$ \frac{\overline{GD}}{\overline{DF}} = \frac{1}{x(x+2)}.$$

### Areas Computation

Now we only need to compute areas of triangles with fixed altitude and a given ratio between bases.

Firstly we have
$$[ACF] = [ABC](1+x).$$

Then
$$[AFE] = [ACF] \frac{\overline{AE}}{\overline{AC}},$$
that is
$$[AFE] = [ABC]\frac{(x+1)^2}{x}.$$

We also have
$$[GFE] = [AFE]\frac{\overline{GE}}{\overline{AE}},$$
yielding
$$ [GFE] =2[ABC]\frac{(x+1)^2}{x(x+2)}.$$

Finally observe that
$$\frac{[DFE]}{[GDE]} = \frac{\overline{GD}}{\overline{DF}} = \frac{1}{x(x+2)}.$$

Thus we have the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{[DFE]}{[GDE]} = \frac{1}{x(x+2)}\\
[DFE] + [GDE] =2[ABC]\frac{(x+1)^2}{x(x+2)}. 
\end{cases}
$$

leading, once solved, to the desired result, i.e.
$$\boxed{[DFE] = 2[ABC]} $$

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

### Proof for any point $P=(k,P(k)), \ \forall k \in[-\frac{\sqrt3}3s,\frac{\sqrt3}3s], \ s\in \mathbb{R}$

---

The area of triangles $\triangle DEF$ and $\triangle ABC$ can be written as:
$\require{cancel}$
$$A_{\triangle ABC}=\pm\frac12
\det\begin{vmatrix}
A_X&A_Y&1\\
B_X&B_Y&1\\
C_X&C_Y&1\\
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$
A_{\triangle DEF}=\pm\frac12
\det\begin{vmatrix}
D_X&D_Y&1\\
E_X&E_Y&1\\
F_X&F_Y&1\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

For any circumcircle of an equilateral triangle, the radius is equal to $\frac{\sqrt3}3 s$, where $s$ is the side of the triangle, thus the circumcircle is defined by $$x^2+y^2=\frac13s^2$$
Which means, the $P$ is defined by $P(x)=\sqrt{\frac13s^2-x^2}$, or $\big(x,P(x)\big)$

---

For an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$ with side $s$, the vertices $A,B$ and $C$ are:
$$\begin{align}
A=&\Bigg(-\frac{\sqrt{-s^4+8 s^2-4}}{2 \sqrt{3} s},\frac{\sqrt{3} s^2-2 \sqrt{3}}{6 s}\Bigg)\\
B=&\Bigg(0,\frac{s}{\sqrt{3}}\Bigg)\\
C=&\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{-s^4+8 s^2-4}}{2 \sqrt{3} s},\frac{\sqrt{3} s^2-2 \sqrt{3}}{6 s}\Bigg)\\
\end{align}$$

Then suppose we have a square matrix $M_1$, arranged as discussed above, that contains points $A,B$ and $C$, the area of the $\triangle ABC$, will be:
$$A_{\triangle ABC}=\pm\frac12\det|M_1|=\frac{\left(s^2+2\right) \sqrt{-s^4+8 s^2-4}}{12 s^2}$$

However, we assume $s=1$, because it simplifies the process. Then we have:
$$A_{\triangle ABC}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

Given $(k,P(k))$, $\forall k \in [-\frac{\sqrt3}3,\frac{\sqrt3}3]$, which defines point $P$, you get points $D,E$ and $F$ as:
$$\begin{align}
D=&\Bigg(\frac{-\sqrt{1-3 k^2}+3 k+1}{2 \sqrt{1-3 k^2}+6 k+4},\frac{5 \sqrt{1-3 k^2}-3 k+1}{2 \sqrt{3} \left(\sqrt{1-3 k^2}+3 k+2\right)}\Bigg)\\
E=&\Bigg(\frac{3 k}{2-2 \sqrt{1-3 k^2}},-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}\Bigg)\\
F=&\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{1-3 k^2}+3 k-1}{2 \left(\sqrt{1-3 k^2}-3 k+2\right)},\frac{5 \sqrt{1-3 k^2}+3 k+1}{2 \sqrt{3} \left(\sqrt{1-3 k^2}-3 k+2\right)}\Bigg)\\
\end{align}$$

Suppose now we have a matrix $M_2$, arranged as discussed above, that contains the points $D,E$ and $F$, the area of $\triangle DEF$, for $s=1$, is:
$$\begin{align}
A_{\triangle DEF}=&\pm\frac12\det|M_2|\\
=&\frac{-2592 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{1-3 k^2} k^2+216 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{1-3 k^2}-216 \sqrt{3}}{216 \left(\sqrt{1-3 k^2}-1\right) \left(\sqrt{1-3 k^2}-3 k+2\right) \left(\sqrt{1-3 k^2}+3 k+2\right)}
\end{align}$$
Simplifying that actually gives us:
$$\begin{align}
A_{\triangle DEF}=&\frac{-216 \sqrt{3} \left(12 \sqrt{1-3 k^2} k^2-\sqrt{1-3 k^2}+1\right)}{2\cdot-216\sqrt{3} \left(12 \sqrt{1-3 k^2} k^2-\sqrt{1-3 k^2}+1\right)}\\
=&\frac{\cancel{-216} \sqrt{3} \cancel{\left(12 \sqrt{1-3 k^2} k^2-\sqrt{1-3 k^2}+1\right)}}{2\cdot\cancel{-216} \cancel{(12 \sqrt{1-3 k^2} k^2-\sqrt{1-3 k^2}+1})}\\
=&\frac{\sqrt3}2
\end{align}$$

### This goes to show that for any value of $k$, and thus, for any point $P$, the area will always be twice that of $\triangle ABC$.

### Take note, however, the $k$ must be an element of $[-\frac{\sqrt3}3s,\frac{\sqrt3}3s]$

Comment: As you can see, there is no more need for a proof by induction

Comment: It must be a university solution which confuse me a lot because I am a high school student. They are all new for me. I don’t even understand how to get the coordinate of vertices. But thank you so much for your effort. I will ask my teacher to explain me about your solution. :)

Comment: It's actually quite elementary, albeit computationally exhausting. It will help you a lot if you read up on linear algebra. As for getting coordinates of the vertices, you'll find that the distance formula, or simply, Pythagorean's theorem, to be very helpful. I know my answer is not at all intuitive, so I'm sure your professor has a clearer, more intuitive answer.

Comment: I will learn more about that:) thank you , I appreciate it.

Comment: But one question , the coordinate of Vertices A,B,C could be change right ? it depends on how we set it?

Comment: Yes. What I have shown you is the general formula for any equilateral triangle with side $s$. Meaning, as long as the center stays at point of origin, no matter how long/short the sides are of your triangle, the formula will define where the vertices will be. *However*, with regards points $D, E, and $F$, they only hold for $s=1$, otherwise, the formulas would have been awfully long :)

Comment: I will learn more but now it’s 12am  late night, I have to sleep!  Thanks once again !

Comment: I propose what I think is a more "natural" approach. Based on Menelao's Theorem. No trigonometry or coordinate geometry required. Have a look, if you like!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Without loss of generality, let

\begin{align} 
O&=(0,0),\quad
A=(1,0),\quad 
B=(-\tfrac12,\tfrac{\sqrt3}2),\quad
C=(-\tfrac12,-\tfrac{\sqrt3}2),\quad
P=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)
,\\
&\text{and let }S\text{ be the area of }\triangle ABC
.
\end{align}
Then 
\begin{align} 
|AB|&=|BC|=|CA|=\sqrt3,\quad
\angle BAE=120^\circ,\quad
\angle APB=120^\circ,\quad
\angle EPA=60^\circ
,\\
\angle OAP&=\angle APO=\angle PCA=\tfrac\phi2,\quad
\angle PAE=60^\circ+\tfrac\phi2,\quad
\angle AEP=60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2
,\\
S&=\tfrac{3\sqrt3}4
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
D&=(-\tfrac12, \tfrac32\cot\tfrac\phi2)
,\\
|AD|^2&=|AM|^2+|DM|^2=\tfrac94\,(1+\cot^2\tfrac\phi2)
=\frac9{4\sin^2\tfrac\phi2}
,\\
|AD|&=\frac3{2\sin\tfrac\phi2}
,\\
|AP|^2&=2\,(1-\cos\phi)
,\\
\triangle AEP:\quad
|AE|^2&=\frac{|AP|^2\sin^2\angle EPA}{\sin^2\angle AEP}
=\frac{3\,(1-\cos\phi)}{2\sin^2(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2)}
=\frac{3\,\sin^2\tfrac\phi2}{\sin^2(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2)}
,\\
|AE|&=
\frac{\sqrt3\,\sin\tfrac\phi2}{\sin(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2)}
,\\
\triangle BCF,\triangle AFC:\quad 
|CF|&=
\frac{2\,S}{\sqrt3\,(\sin\tfrac\phi2+\sin(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2))}
=
\frac{3}{2\,(\sin\tfrac\phi2+\sin(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2))}
,
\end{align}

which leads to
\begin{align} 
E&=(1+|AE|\,\cos30^\circ,\,|AE|\,\sin30^\circ)
=
\left(1+
\frac{3\,\sin\tfrac\phi2}{2\sin(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2)},
\,
\frac{\sqrt3\,\sin\tfrac\phi2}{2\sin(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2)}
\right)
,\\
F&=\left(
-\tfrac12+|CF|\cos(30^\circ+\tfrac\phi2)
,\, 
-\tfrac{\sqrt3}2+|CF|\sin(30^\circ+\tfrac\phi2)
\right)
\\
&=
\left(
-\tfrac12+
\frac{3\,\sin(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2)}{2\,(\sin\tfrac\phi2+\sin(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2))}
,\, 
-\tfrac{\sqrt3}2+
\frac{3\,\cos(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2)}{2\,(\sin\tfrac\phi2+\sin(60^\circ-\tfrac\phi2))}
\right)
.
\end{align}

The area of $\triangle DFE$ in terms of coordinates of $D,F,E$ is known 
to be expressed as

\begin{align} 
\tfrac12(D_xF_y+F_xE_y+E_xD_y-D_yF_x-F_yE_x-E_yD_x)
.
\end{align}

The following `maxima` code

```
Dx:-1/2$
Dy:3/2*cos(phi/2)/sin(phi/2)$
Fx:-1/2+3/(2*(sin(1/2*phi)+cos(1/6*%pi+1/2*phi)))*sin(%pi/3-phi/2)$
Fy:-sqrt(3)/2+3/(2*(sin(1/2*phi)+cos(1/6*%pi+1/2*phi)))*cos(%pi/3-phi/2)$
Ex:1+3*sin(phi/2)/(2*sin(%pi/3-phi/2))$
Ey:sqrt(3)*sin(phi/2)/(2*sin(%pi/3-phi/2))$
factor(trigexpand((Dx*Fy+Fx*Ey+Ex*Dy-Dy*Fx-Fy*Ex-Ey*Dx)/2));
```

gives this result:

\begin{align} 
\frac{3^{3/2}(\sin^2\tfrac\phi2-3\cos^2\tfrac\phi2)}{
2\,(\sin\tfrac\phi2-\sqrt3\cos\tfrac\phi2)
(\sin\tfrac\phi2+\sqrt3\cos\tfrac\phi2)
},
\end{align}

trivially simplified further to get $\frac{3\sqrt3}2$,
which is indeed, twice the area of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: Ohh well! Thank you ! Now I get another solution.